# Install Windows Store App via Visual Studio Installer (C#) and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I want to install a **Windows Store App** with an easy to use **msi Installer**.
I'm using **Visual Studio Installer** to create the msi package.
The Windows Store App can, without the store, only be installed via **PowerShell**.

Working:
Installer completes successfull.
Needed changes to "AllowAllTrustedApps" and the installation of the certificate are working.

Not working:
Installing the appx package via C# Code in PowerShell doesn't do anything

Installing the certificate via PowerShell works:

```
using (RunspaceInvoke invoker = new RunspaceInvoke())
            {
                invoker.Invoke("certutil.exe -addstore -f \"TrustedPeople\" \"C:\\Program Files\\App_1.0.0.0_x64.cer\"");
            }
```

Installing the appx doesn't work:

```
using (RunspaceInvoke invoker = new RunspaceInvoke())
            {
                invoker.Invoke("Add-AppxPackage -Path \"C:\\Program Files\\App_1.0.0.0_x64.appx\"}");
            }
```

Also tried this with .ps1 Files.
My thought was that the code can't handle the progress bar that appears when the app is installed in PowerShell and kills it. So I wanted to start a new PowerShell window:

```
using (RunspaceInvoke invoker = new RunspaceInvoke())
            {
                invoker.Invoke("cmd \c start powershell -Command {Add-AppxPackage -Path \"C:\\Program Files\\App_1.0.0.0_x64.appx\"}");
            }
```

But that generates an exception I can't really read, because it closes the window very fast. The exception contains the following:

> Adding the package was denied, because the process uses the local
>   systemaccount.

But it's running with administrator rights! Installing everything with direct use of PowerShell works. So every command should be correct.
Any ideas whats wrong? Don't know what to google for anymore...
Thanks in advance

Regards,
Sebastian Neurohr

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure out the root cause & fix? I am trying something similar, need advice.